# Failed to add ICE candidate: OperationError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Error processing ICE candidate

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, angular7, videochat, video-conferencing

I am using `Angular 7`, `Webrtc` to make simple video conference web applications. I am creating four different RTCPeerConnections for pc1Local, pc1Remote, pc2Local, pc2Remote.
on start() function I am accessing the local camera and displaying stream on video1 id in Html. And in call() I am setting two remote users. One remote user is getting displayed properly but the third video stream is not getting displayed. Please help me to solve this.

My code is :

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { ChatWindowService } from '../chat-box/service/chat-window.service';
    import { error } from 'util';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-test-video-calling',
      templateUrl: './test-video-calling.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./test-video-calling.component.scss']
    })
    export class TestVideoCallingComponent implements OnInit {

       @ViewChild('video1', { static: false }) video1: ElementRef;
       @ViewChild('video2', { static: false }) video2: ElementRef;
       @ViewChild('video3', { static: false }) video3: ElementRef;  

       public pc1Local;
       public pc1Remote;
       public pc2Local;
       public pc2Remote;
       public browser = <any>navigator;
       public videoStream;
       public audioTracks ;
       public videoTracks ;
       public localStream;

       constructor(){}

       public offerOptions = {
        offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
        offerToReceiveVideo: 1
       };

       start(){
        this.videoStream = this.video1.nativeElement;
        this.browser.getUserMedia = this.getAllUserMedia();
        console.log('Requesting local stream');
        let constraints = { audio: true, video: { minFrameRate: 60, width: 400, height: 300 } };
        this.browser.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream: any) => {
          this.videoStream.srcObject = stream;  
          this.localStream = stream;
       });
     }

    call(){
        `enter code here`this.videoTracks = this.localStream.getVideoTracks();
        this.audioTracks = this.localStream.getAudioTracks();

        console.log('Starting calls');
         if (this.audioTracks.length > 0) {
      console.log(`Using audio device: ${this.audioTracks[0].label}`);
    }
    if (this.videoTracks.length > 0) {
      console.log(`Using video device: ${this.videoTracks[0].label}`);
    }

    const servers = null;

    this.pc1Local = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    this.pc1Remote = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);

    this.pc1Local.onicecandidate = (event:any) =>{
      this.handleCandidate(event.candidate, this.pc1Remote, 'pc1: ', 'local');
    }

    this.pc1Remote.onicecandidate = (event:any)=>{
      this.handleCandidate(event.candidate, this.pc1Local, 'pc1: ', 'remote');
    };

    this.pc1Remote.ontrack = (streamData:any)=>{
      if (this.video2.nativeElement.srcObject !== streamData.streams[0]) {
        this.video2.nativeElement.srcObject = streamData.streams[0]; 
        console.log('pc1: received remote stream');
        if (!streamData.stop && streamData.getTracks) {
          streamData.stop = function () {
            this.getTracks().forEach(function (track: any) {
              track.stop();
            });
          };
        }
      }
    }


    this.pc2Local = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    this.pc2Remote = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);

    console.log("****before this.pc2Local.onicecandidate ******");
    this.pc2Local.onicecandidate = (event:any) =>{
      console.log("**************adding ice candidate : pc2Local***************",event);
      this.handleCandidate(event.candidate, this.pc2Remote, 'pc2: ', 'local');
    }
    console.log("****after this.pc2Local.onicecandidate ******");

    this.pc2Remote.onicecandidate = (event:any)=>{
      console.log("**************adding ice candidate : pc2Remote***************",event);
      this.handleCandidate(event.candidate, this.pc2Local, 'pc2: ', 'remote');
    };

    this.pc2Remote.ontrack = (streamData1)=>{
      if (this.video3.nativeElement.srcObject !== streamData1.streams[0]) {
        this.video3.nativeElement.srcObject = streamData1.streams[0];
        console.log('pc2: received remote stream');
        console.log("****** pc2: remote streamData : ********",streamData1);

        if (!streamData1.stop && streamData1.getTracks) {
          streamData1.stop = function () {
            this.getTracks().forEach(function (track: any) {
              track.stop();
            });
          };
        }
      }
    }


    this.localStream.getTracks().forEach((track: any) => {
      console.log("************pc1 adding track*************");
        this.pc1Local.addTrack(track, this.localStream);
    });

    console.log('Adding local stream to pc1Local');
    this.pc1Local.createOffer(this.offerOptions).then((event:any)=>{
      this.pc1Local.setLocalDescription(event);
      console.log(`Offer from pc1Local\n${event.sdp}`);
    this.pc1Remote.setRemoteDescription(event);

    this.pc1Remote.createAnswer().then((desc)=>{
        try{
          this.pc1Remote.setLocalDescription(desc);
            console.log(`Answer from pc1Remote\n${desc.sdp}`);
            this.pc1Local.setRemoteDescription(desc);
        }catch(error){
          console.log(`Failed to create session description: ${error.toString()}`);
        }
      });
    });

    this.localStream.getTracks().forEach((track: any) => {
      console.log("************pc2 adding track*************");
      this.pc2Local.addTrack(track, this.localStream);
  });

  console.log('Adding local stream to pc2Local');
  this.pc2Local.createOffer(this.offerOptions).then((event:any)=>{
    this.pc1Local.setLocalDescription(event);
    console.log(`Offer from pc1Local\n${event.sdp}`);
  this.pc2Remote.setRemoteDescription(event);

  this.pc2Remote.createAnswer().then((desc)=>{
      try{
        this.pc2Remote.setLocalDescription(desc);
          console.log(`Answer from pc1Remote\n${desc.sdp}`);
          this.pc2Local.setRemoteDescription(desc);
      }catch(error){
        console.log(`Failed to create session description: ${error.toString()}`);
      }
    });
  });
   }

  public handleCandidate(candidate, dest, prefix, type) {
    dest.addIceCandidate(candidate).then(this.onAddIceCandidateSuccess,this.onAddIceCandidateError);
  console.log(`${prefix}New ${type} ICE candidate: ${candidate ? candidate.candidate : '(null)'}`);
  }


  public onAddIceCandidateSuccess() {
    console.log('AddIceCandidate success.');
  }

  public onAddIceCandidateError(error) {
    console.log(`Failed to add ICE candidate: ${error.toString()}`);
  }
  public getAllUserMedia() {
    console.log("*****************Inside getAllUserMedia ************");
    return this.browser.getUserMedia ||
      this.browser.webkitGetUserMedia ||
      this.browser.mozGetUserMedia ||
      this.browser.msGetUserMedia;
   }

   ngOnInit() {
   }
}
```

My Html File is

```
    <div class="container">
    <video #video1 playsinline autoplay muted></video>
    <video #video2 playsinline autoplay></video>
    <video #video3 playsinline autoplay></video>

    <div>
        <button id="startButton" (click)="start()">Start</button>
        <button id="callButton"  (click)="call()">Call</button>
        <button id="hangupButton" (click)="stop()">Hang Up</button>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Problem is `this.pc2Local.onicecandidate` is not executing. and I am getting an error given bellow

```
`Failed to add ICE candidate: OperationError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Error processing ICE candidate`
```